# 3-dimensional Brownian motion, probability distribution of first hitting time to a sphere

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk

What is the probability density function or probability distribution of the time when 3-dimensional Brownian motion (no drift) starting from origin hits a sphere (ball) centered at the origin for the first time?

Brownian motion is also known as the Wiener process. For simplicity and I think without loss of generality, the 3-dimensional normal Wiener process can be parameterized such a way that the random variable follows in each dimension a zero-mean normal distribution of variance $t$ as function of time $t$. Likewise, the sphere radius can be set to 1.

The first hitting time can also be viewed as the exit or killing time in a killed Wiener process. I'm looking for an answer that leads to a way to generate pseudo random numbers from the first exit time distribution.

Comment: I don't know an immediate answer but I think that it would help if you added some more parameters (which might seem "obvious") that would help make it clearer for a wider audience such as the radius of the sphere, how many steps per unit time we have, size of step etc. In any case, +1.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake OK I tried to do that. I'm not sure if this is the easiest parameterization to work with. I Hope so.

Comment: [This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176994833) gives the Laplace transform of this hitting time in terms of a Bessel function, see eq. 4. See also Theorem 3 in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-6748-2_8) for the joint density of $(\tau,B_\tau)$.

Comment: @Michh there's a scan of the second paper Pei Shu, "Brownian Exit Distribution of a Ball", Seminar on Stochastic Processes, 1985, Birkhäuser, Boston, 1986 [here](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~ehsu/Brownian%20Exit%20Distribution%20of%20a%20Ball.pdf).